# how a request would be ADFS authenticated non-interactively?

Tags: node.js, adfs

There is a requirement in my project to Authenticate user using ADFS at back end without user interaction with ADFS Login Page.Any possible way to achieve it(maybe by Certificate Authentication only)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the WS-Fed active profile (ala WCF).

Or for ADFS 4.0, with OpenID Connect / OAuth you could use client credential flow (typically server to server) where authentication is via knowledge of a secret key.

If from client, use resource owner password flow.